# Google App Engine, Java Frameworks?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, google-app-engine

I'm going to implement an web app in gae.
I was wondering which is the best framwork for that?
I used the `struts2` but it seems to be not supported.
Is there any MVC or similat inside the GAE?
What do you think is the best way?

PS: the application should be basically a collections of user profiles (with different informations) + a collections of place descriptions (which picture, descriptions, and user comments).

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC in a Google App Engine Java world](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/862003/mvc-in-a-google-app-engine-java-world)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the list of libraries and frameworks that are [tested to work on GAE](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/WillItPlayInJava). It seems that Struts 2 is supported via a workaround.

Personally I'd go with something more modern such as [Play](http://www.playframework.org/), [Sitebricks](http://code.google.com/p/google-sitebricks/wiki/Appengine) or my favorite: [JAX-RS with Freemarker](http://www.citytechinc.com/us/en/blog/2008/12/spring_jax-rs_free.html).

Also, if you are not afraid to try something new go with GWT (as @Carlos already suggested). It's a steep learning curve, but worth it.

Comment: the solution of JAX-RS and freemaker seems good (any other ref on that?). 
for the GWT the thing that scarry me is the fact that people need to install addons for using the website.

Comment: err, no. GWT is compiled to javascript - no add-on is necessary for the user. Only for developer IF debugging is needed.

Comment: Here are some projects made with GWT. No addon needed to use them: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/examples/

Comment: probably was just me. i mean, first time i tried chrome told me to download an add-on for letting GWT work.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/tutorial/appengine); it allows you to build RIA applications and its supported directly by Google Plugin for Eclipse. For dependency injection, you can use Guice for Server Components and Gin for GWT client classes.

Comment: well, gwt needs extension to install don't know if people would like to install it before even opening the website.

Comment: what extension are you talking about ?? a eclipse plugin for development yes, but the end result is strictly HTML/JS/CSS. My favourite GWT + REST based services !